# Relaciones sin id en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas. 
Me gustaría relacionar dos tablas en Laravel, desde los modelos, sin usar el campo id.

O sea, tengo una tabla con un campo en común, que no es ID. Y me gustaría relaccionarlos.

tabla 1
campo 1
campo 2
campo a -> Campo con el mismo valor en las dos tablas

Tabla 2
campo 3
campo 6
campo a -> Campo con el mismo valor en las dos tablas

Ahora mismo uso:

```
 class Device extends Model
{
  public function alarms()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Alarm::class, 'device_imei', 'device_imei');
}
}
```

Pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser algo así

```
public function alarms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Alarm', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

**foreign_key**: es el nombre del campo foraneo del modelo en el que estamos declarando.

**local_key**: es el nombre del campo del modelo con el que estamos realizando la relación en este caso `'App\Alarm'`.

**App\Alarm**: es el modelo que queremos relacionar, fijate que lo pasamos como *string* y añadiendo en ***namespace***.

Luego puedes hacer uso de esta forma:

```
$alarms = App\MiModelo::find(1)->alarms;

foreach ($alarms as $alarm) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. No la había leído hasta ahora. Un saludo.